# Change php time() stored in DB to an ISO 8601 timestamp

Tags: jquery, timeago

I have stored time of comment in DB as `time();` now I need to use that to be able to use JQUERY TIME AGO PLUGIN. But not have any idea as how to convert it in to "2008-07-17T09:24:17Z" format so it can be used in plugin.

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: I can try with php date function but what does T and Z means?

Comment: completely disagree it to be duplicate....I never asked for javascript options. Request everyone to read the question first and  then mark sensible duplicates

Comment: You asked for PHP answers, but tagged the question as jQuery. This means you are going to attract answers relating to jQuery and JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In php,

```
 $isostring = date('c',$timevalue);
```

gets you the ISO8601 string. See here:  http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

T is a separator splitting the date from the time. Z is a timezone indicator, meaning so-called Zulu time. That's aviator shorthand for the null timezone, also known as Universal Time Coordinated (UTC) formerly known as Greenwich Mean Time (GMT).

Comment: thanks for answer...let me check and come back.

Answer (score 0):

PHP has several constants that are used to covert to common date formats. Assuming you are accessing the time from a database, you can use `strtotime()` to convert and then use the `DATE_ISO8601` constant in PHP.

```
$dateformatted = date(DATE_ISO8601, strtotime($datefromdatabase));
```

Comment: didn't worked as required by timeago plugin